# How can I configure Wine's default paper settings?

Tags: gentoo, printing, locale, wine

I'm having trouble with the locale settings in my Microsoft Office Wine bottle/prefix. When I created it, I had followed the [Gentoo Localization Guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/guide-localization.xml)'s suggestion to not set LC_ALL. However, when I try to print from any application in the bottle, the printer is told to use A4, even though the rest of my locale settings are set to en_US. This is particularly troublesome when using Office 2010 apps, which show Letter as the paper size, but send A4 to the printer. Notepad is an easy test, as it will show what is actually set (A4).

I created a new bottle with LC_ALL set, and it defaults to Letter (using the Notepad test). What I'd like to do is fix my existing bottle. Is this possible? The WineHQ forums haven't been too helpful so far.

Comment: I've worked around this by installing Office in a different bottle, but I'm going to leave this question open in case someone has an answer. I'll hold onto the original bottle for testing.

Comment: Set LC_PAPER, perhaps? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148987/4671