# What should I set my locale to and what are the implications of doing so?

Tags: locale

This question was stimulated by asking the question
[Chromium browser does not allow setting the default paper size for "Print to File"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148987/4671), and also by a conversation with @Gilles on chat. As pointed out by @don_crissti, and as verified by me, changing the locale (at least `LC_PAPER`) makes a difference in what paper size is selected.

I had never given much thought to what to select, and had always gone with `en_US.UTF-8` because it seemed like a reasonable default choice.

However, per @Gilles on chat (see conversation starting at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17017095#17017095). Extracts:

> Gilles: LC_PAPER defaults to $LANG
>
> Gilles: You must have LANG=en_US.UTF-8. That's a bad idea: it sets
>   LC_COLLATE and that's almost always a bad thing
>
> Gilles: LC_COLLATE doesn't describe correct collation, it's too
>   restrictive (it goes character by character) remove LANG and instead
>   set LC_CTYPE and LC_PAPER
>
> Gilles: plus LC_MESSAGES if you want messages in a language other than
>   English

Clearly, there are issues here I am not aware of, and I am sure many others are as well. So, what issues should you consider when setting locales, and how should you set them? I've always just run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` in Debian, and not thought twice about it.

Specific question: Should I set my locale to en_IN.UTF-8? Are there any drawbacks of doing so?

See also: [Does (should) LC_COLLATE affect character ranges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15980/4671)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) settings are user preferences that relate to your culture.

### Locale names

On all current unix variants that I know of (but not on a few antiques), locale names follow the same pattern:

- An [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) lowercase two-letter language code, or an [ISO 639-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2) three-letter language code if the language has no two-letter code. For example, `en` for English, `de` for German, `ja` for Japanese, `uk` for Ukrainian, `ber` for Berber, …
- For many but not all languages, an underscore `_` followed by an [ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) uppercase two-letter country code. Thus: `en_US` for US English, `en_UK` for British English, `fr_CA` Canadian (Québec) French, `de_DE` for German of Germany, `de_AT` for German of Austria, `ja_JP` for Japanese (of Japan), etc.
- Optionally, a dot `.` followed by the name of a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) such as `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1`, `KOI8-U`, `GB2312`, `Big5`, etc. With GNU libc at least (I don't know how widespread this is), case and punctuation is ignored in encoding names. For example, `zh_CN.UTF-8` is Mandarin (simplified) Chinese encoded in UTF-8, while `zh_CN` is Mandarin Chinese encoded in GB2312, and `zh_TW` is Taiwanese (traditional) Chinese encoded in Big5.
- Optionally, an at sign `@` followed by the name of a variant. The meaning of variants is locale-dependent. For example, many European countries have an `@euro` locale variant where the currency sign is € and where the encoding is one that includes this character (ISO 8859-15 or ISO 8859-16), as opposed to the unadorned variant with the older currency sign. For example, `en_IE` (English, Ireland) uses the latin1 (ISO 8859-1) encoding and £ as the currency symbol while `en_IE@euro` uses the latin9 (ISO 8859-15) encoding and € as the currency symbol.

In addition, there are two locale names that exist on all unix-like system: `C` and `POSIX`. These names are synonymous and mean computerese, i.e. default settings that are appropriate for data that is parsed by a computer program.

### Locale settings

The following locale categories are defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html):

- `LC_CTYPE`: the character set used by terminal applications: classification data (which characters are letters, punctuation, spaces, invalid, etc.) and case conversion. Text utilities typically heed `LC_CTYPE` to determine character boundaries.
- `LC_COLLATE`: collation (i.e. sorting) order. This setting is of very limited use for several reasons:

  - Most languages have intricate rules that depend on what is being sorted (e.g. dictionary words and proper names might not use the same order) and cannot be expressed by `LC_COLLATE`.
  - There are few applications where proper sort order matters which are performed by software that uses locale settings. For example, word processors store the language and encoding of a file in the file itself (otherwise the file wouldn't be processed correctly on a system with different locale settings) and don't care about the locale settings specified by the environment.
  - `LC_COLLATE` can have nasty side effects, in particular because it causes the sort order A < a < B < …, which makes “between A and Z” include the lowercase letters a through y. In particular, very common regular expressions [like `[A-Z]` break some applications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/does-should-lc-collate-affect-character-ranges).
- `LC_MESSAGES`: the language of informational and error messages.
- `LC_NUMERIC`: number formatting: decimal and thousands separator.
  Many applications hard-code `.` as a decimal separator. This makes `LC_NUMERIC` not very useful and potentially dangerous:

  - Even if you set it, you'll still see the default format pretty often.
  - You're likely to get into a situation where one application produces locale-dependent output and another application expects `.` to be the decimal point, or `,` to be a field separator.
- `LC_MONETARY`: like `LC_NUMERIC`, but for amounts of local currency.
  Very few applications use this.
- `LC_TIME`: date and time formatting: weekday and month names, 12 or 24-hour clock, order of date parts, punctuation, etc.

GNU libc, which you'll find on non-embedded Linux, defines additional locale categories:

- `LC_PAPER`: the default paper size (defined by height and width).
- `LC_NAME`, `LC_ADDRESS`, `LC_TELEPHONE`, `LC_MEASUREMENT`, `LC_IDENTIFICATION`: I don't know of any application that uses these.

### Environment variables

Applications that use locale settings determine them from environment variables.

- Then the value of the `LANG` environment variable is used unless overridden by another setting. If `LANG` is not set, the default locale is `C`.
- The `LC_xxx` names can be used as environment variables.
- If `LC_ALL` is set, then all other values are ignored; this is primarily useful to set `LC_ALL=C` run applications that need to produce the same output regardless of where they are run.
- In addition, GNU libc [uses `LANGUAGE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-gettextized-software.html#Using-gettextized-software) to define fallbacks for `LC_MESSAGES` (e.g. `LANGUAGE=fr_BE:fr_FR:en` to prefer Belgian French, or if unavailable France French, or if unavailable English).

### Installing locales

Locale data can be large, so some distributions don't ship them in a usable form and instead require an additional installation step.

- On Debian, to install locales, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and select from the list in the dialog box, or edit [`/etc/locale.gen`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=locale.gen&sektion=5) and then run [`locale-gen`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=locale-gen&sektion=8).
- On Ubuntu, to install locales, run [`locale-gen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/locale-gen.8.html) with the names of the locales as arguments.

You can [define your own locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03).

### Recommendation

The useful settings are:

- Set `LC_CTYPE` to the language and encoding that you encode your text files in. Ensure that your terminals use that encoding.
  For most languages, only the encoding matters. There are a few exceptions; for example, an uppercase `i` is `I` in most languages but `İ` in Turkish (`tr_TR`).
- Set `LC_MESSAGES` to the language that you want to see messages in.
- Set `LC_PAPER` to `en_US` if you want US Letter to be the default paper size and just about anything else (e.g. `en_GB`) if you want A4.
- Optionally, set `LC_TIME` to your favorite time format.

As explained above, avoid setting `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_NUMERIC`. If you use `LANG`, explicitly override these two categories by setting them to `C`.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for the detailed answer. Where is a good place to override the default settings on Debian? Since I need an A4 paper size, I guess I need to override the default value of `LC_PAPER`. And can I update this across the system without rebooting?

Comment: @FaheemMitha [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables) And if you want to set it system-wide, on Debian, there's also `/etc/default/locale`. These files take effect when you log in; you can do `export LC_PAPER=…` in a shell to affect commands launched from that shell.