# Problem with locale: "Setting locale failed."

Tags: debian, locale

I have a problem with locale and I can't found any solution that works!

Every tutorial is similar to this: [Perl warning Setting locale failed in Debian](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian).

This is the problem with locale:

```
pi @ server [~]:
$ > sudo deluser --remove-home cm22
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Looking for files to backup/remove ...
Removing user `cm22' ...
Warning: group `cm22' has no more members.
Done.
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you post the output of `locale`, `locale -a` and `env | grep -e LANG -e LC_`?

Comment: The output is: `pi @ server [~]:
$ > locale -a and env | grep -e LANG -e  LC_?
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 11):

Debian saves network bandwidth by shipping locale definitions in a form that isn't directly usable, where information that is shared between locales (e.g. `en_US` and `en_CA` are very similar) is stored in a single file. Usable locale definitions must be generated on each machine. To save CPU time and disk space, only locales requested by the system administrator are generated.

Run the following command as root to configure the set of locales to generate:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Alternatively, edit the file `/etc/locale.gen` and comment out the lines corresponding to the locales you want (lines beginning with `#` are comment lines). For example, if you want the `en_GB.UTF-8` locale, you need to have a line containing

```
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Once you've edited `/etc/locale.gen`, run `locale-gen` to regenerate the locale definitions.

The value `UTF-8` that you've set for `LC_CTYPE` is invalid. You need to use a valid locale name, e.g. `LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8`. You can leave `LC_CTYPE` unset: it'll default to the value of `LANG`. Though [I rather recommend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so/149129#149129) to leave `LANG` unset and set `LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8` and `LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8` (`LC_MESSAGES` effectively defaults to English, if you were using another language then you should set it as well).

Comment: I change `/etc/locale.gen`. But how set `LC_CTYPE` ? Thank you

Comment: @anerdev Edit whichever file has the bad definition of `LC_TYPE` to fix it. It could be in your home directory or under `/etc`. Try `grep -s LC_CTYPE ~/.* || grep -rs LC_CTYPE /etc` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not explicitly set `LC_CTYPE`, type :

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

(replace `en_US`, for your desired LANG/CTYPE required definition)

Although verbose, typing:

```
locale LC_CTYPE
```

will provide the current setting value.

[See locale for further reading](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/locale.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a virgin copy of raspbian.

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```