# Locale error on Debian

Tags: debian, locale

On my Debian Wheezy VPS I keep getting the errors relating to locale and locale changes, when switching users, for example:

```
-su: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
```

And when doing almost anything related to installation (apt-get and dpkg):

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

I've looked into it, and found several questions about this kind of errors already.

The output of `locale -a` is:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

I've also tried installing the locales package, which didn't work either, for example `locale-gen`, doesn't change anything.

**Edit**: The output of `strace locale -a` is the following (a whole bunch bunch of text, be warned)

```
execve("/usr/bin/locale", ["locale", "-a"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x191b000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c1353000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30161, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 30161, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe6c134b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\357\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1603600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3717176, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fe6c0daa000
mprotect(0x7fe6c0f2c000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fe6c112c000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x182000) = 0x7fe6c112c000
mmap(0x7fe6c1131000, 18488, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c1131000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c134a000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c1349000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c1348000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fe6c1349700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fe6c112c000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x606000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fe6c1355000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fe6c134b000, 30161)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x191b000
brk(0x193c000)                          = 0x193c000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c1352000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fe6c1352000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "locale: ", 8locale: )                 = 8
write(2, "Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default l"..., 37Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale) = 37
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27: No such file or directory) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "locale: ", 8locale: )                 = 8
write(2, "Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to defaul"..., 40Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale) = 40
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27: No such file or directory) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.utf8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "locale: ", 8locale: )                 = 8
write(2, "Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default"..., 39Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale) = 39
write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27: No such file or directory) = 27
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=168, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2570, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fe6c1352000
lseek(3, 2570, SEEK_SET)                = 2570
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
munmap(0x7fe6c1352000, 2570)            = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe6c1352000
write(1, "C\n", 2C
)                      = 2
write(1, "C.UTF-8\n", 8C.UTF-8
)                = 8
write(1, "POSIX\n", 6POSIX
)                  = 6
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

**Edit 2**: Output of `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

**Edit 3**: Sorry but, this is **not** a duplicate. As I said, I have looked through a ton ton of questions, and none of the answers have helped me or fixed the issue, including the one you nominated as a duplicate. It may seem like a duplicate, and in theory it is, but since my issue is not solved - I don't think reopening an old question would help the issue get solved sooner than opening a new one.

Comment: Maybe `strace locale -a` tells you which file causes the error message.

Comment: @HaukeLaging that gives a whole bunch of text, I will add it to the question.

Comment: Can you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`?

Comment: Please post the output for gcc -v @HaukeLaging is on the right track.  The Package is actually called `gcc-<version>-locale` See [Debian Package Search - Locale](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=locale).

Comment: I strongly doubt it has anything to do with GCC's locale files, but might be related to the [`locales` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=locales)

Comment: @muru Already tried, didn't work anything.

Comment: @eyoung100 I can try outputting gcc if it will be of any help.

Comment: Try this  Read the First Section of the [Linux From Scratch Book - Chapter 5](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/introduction.html).  Make a list of all the packages just in chapter 5, then download each Debian Equivalent and install them in the order listed.  It will take awhile for me to write up the answer as to why this works, but I believe your toolchain is hosed.

Comment: What was the result of each one of those attempts? Don't tell us, "all I tried didn't work" tell us, what you tried, what was the result (output, error, etc.) and the changes in-between.

Comment: @Braiam There was no output nor error, anything that has given me any sort of output or error I have placed in my post.

Comment: Well, that still isn't telling us anything. You haven't said what was the result of `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, nor the content of `/etc/locale.gen`. Not only error messages are useful. The result of each attempt to fix is as important, as other informative/debugging messages.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that files are missing. Each kind of data can be in one of six files but none exists.

Ich have no Debian to check that but with openSUSE I have e.g. the file `/usr/lib/locale/en_US/LC_CTYPE` and the package it belongs to is `glibc-locale`.

Probably the package name is the same with Debian. You should (re)install it.

Comment: glibc-locale doesn't exist on Debian, glibc does but I'm not sure it's the same.

Comment: It works differently on Debian. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169039/problem-with-locale-setting-locale-failed/169138#169138