# How do I get the language for messages?

Tags: shell, debian, locale

Is there a single command I can use to get the language to use for messages or do I have to check `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_ALL`, `LANG` etc. in some specific order?

Comment: If you want the full story: [What should I set my locale to and what are the implications of doing so?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so/149129#149129)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `locale` information with:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_us.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_us.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The relevant variable for your concern would then be `$LC_MESSAGES`:

```
   LC_MESSAGES
           Formats of informative and diagnostic messages and
           interactive responses.
```

In a sctipt you could source that output to have those environment variables available:

```
$ source <(locale)
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I realize that `LC_MESSAGES` gets a value even if a user has only defined for instance LC_ALL.

Comment: @August Karlstrom: It doesn't; try `echo $LC_MESSAGES`.  But things work as if it did.

Comment: @lcd047 I see, but does the `locale` command always output `LC_MESSAGES`? In that case I can get the language with `locale | grep LC_MESSAGES | awk -F'=' '{ print substr($2, 1, 2) }'`.

Comment: The easier way to do it is mentioned in the answer above: `source <(locale)`.  This will actually define `LC_MESSAGE` and friends in the environment.  But yes, you can also get it from the output of `locale`, perhaps like this: `locale | sed -n '/^LC_MESSAGES/{ s/^.*=//; s/"//g; p }'`.

Comment: @lcd047 I already have `LC_MESSAGES` defined in the environment (exported from `~/.profile`). The compound command should (of course) be `locale | awk -F'=' '$1 == "LC_MESSAGES" { print substr($2, 1, 2) }'` which I think is easier to understand than your version with `sed`.

Comment: @August Karlstrom: Possible.  I've been playing the UNIX game for ~25 years, I suppose I'm deeply stuck in the old-school ways.  Sorry about that. _shrug_