# What value for LANG should I use for "sort -u“ correctly handle Chinese characters?

Tags: sort, locale, unicode

- The context
- Issues found

  - Issue no. 1
  - Issue no. 2
  - Issue no. 3
- The question

## The context

Today, I wanted to keep the unique lines in a file containing Chinese characters. I decided to use the `sort` utility because I'm familiar with that tool and deleting repeated lines in a file is as easy as using the `-u` flag. I learnt that I needed to change the locale to make `sort` work correctly with Chinese characters. I noticed that using different locales made `sort` have different behaviors. In this post, I showed what I found.

I'm aware that the task of deleting repeated lines in a file can be done using multiple tools/programming languages. While I thank anyone that suggests a tool for doing that task, I'm more interested in knowing more about locales and how they affect Unix utilities.

## Issues found

### Issue no. 1

The following is the locale of my system.

```
locale
```

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Consider the following file named `main.txt`

```
䔍
䏝
```

If I try to sort it using `en_US.UTF-8` as my `$LANG`. I lose line no. 2

```
sort -u main.txt
```

```
䔍
```

I have solved this issue by setting `LANG` to `zh_CN.UTF-8`.

```
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
sort -u main.txt
```

```
䔍
䏝
```

I created [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295249) about this issue in Stack Overflow. Someone suggested me changing the locale and it seemed to work, I thought I had solved the problem, but  then I found Issue no. 2 and Issue no. 3 (described below).

### Issue no. 2

Now, let's suppose that we add two lines to our file `main.txt`

```
䔍
䏝
```

If I execute `sort -u` on it while having `LANG` equal to `zh_CN.UTF-8`, I lose line no. 4.

```
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
sort -u main.txt
```

```
䔍

䏝
```

I tried different locales that started with `zh.CN` since the characters are Chinese characters. The uncommented locales are the ones that I tried using.

```
grep '^#\?zh' /etc/locale.gen
```

```
zh_CN.GB18030 GB18030  
zh_CN.GBK GBK  
zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8  
zh_CN GB2312  
#zh_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8  
#zh_HK BIG5-HKSCS  
#zh_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8  
#zh_SG.GBK GBK  
#zh_SG GB2312  
#zh_TW.EUC-TW EUC-TW  
#zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8  
#zh_TW BIG5
```

I noticed that `sort -u` works as expected when setting `LANG` set to `zh_CN.GBK` or `zh_CN.GB18030`. I solved this issue by using either `zh_CN.GBK` or `zh_CN.GB18030`.

Here's the proof that it works as expected when setting `LANG` to `zh_CN.GBK`.

```
export LANG=zh_CN.GBK
sort -u main.txt
```

```
䔍


䏝
```

Here's the proof that it works as expected when setting `LANG` to `zh_CN.GB18030`.

```
export LANG=zh_CN.GB18030
sort -u main.txt
```

```
䔍


䏝
```

### Issue no. 3

Let's suppose that we add two more lines to our file `main.txt`

```
䔍
䏝


书
乙
```

If I use `zh_CN.GB18030` or `zh_CN.GBK`, I lose line no. 6.

```
export LANG=zh_CN.GB18030
sort -u main.txt
```

```
书
䔍


䏝
```

```
export LANG=zh_CN.GBK
sort -u main.txt
```

```
书
䔍


䏝
```

## The question

Which value for `$LANG` should I use for making `sort` actually keep the unique lines in the following file?

```
䔍
䏝


书
乙
```

I previously showed that using `zh_CN.GB18030`, `zh_CN.GBK`, `zh_CN.UTF-8` or `zh_CN` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Related: [What does "LC\_ALL=C" do?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745) and [What is the difference between "sort -u" and "sort | uniq"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/76095)

Answer (score 10):

`sort -u` outputs one of each set of lines that collate the same (have identical sorting order) in the locale.

On GNU systems (systems using the GNU libc), in most locales, many characters¹ have an undefined sorting order which means they end up sorting the same, and there are also characters that are explicitly defined to have the same sorting order.

When bytes cannot be decoded into text, they will often also be ignored or considered to have the same sorting order².

So for `sort -u` to give you unique lines based on byte-to-byte equality comparison whatever encoding the text is written in, you need a locale where every byte can be decoded into a character and a locale with  a total order.

The easiest is to use the `C` locale where there's a one byte == one character mapping (some bytes possibly leading to *undefined* characters) and sorting is based on the byte value (on ASCII-based systems at least) and is the only locale which you're guaranteed to find on any given system.

In your case, to understand why `zh_CN` gives you slightly better behaviour, you can have a look at the locale definitions typically in `/usr/share/i18n/locale` on GNU systems where for `zh_CN` you find:

```
LC_COLLATE
copy "iso14651_t1_pinyin"
END LC_COLLATE
```

Where `iso14651_t1_pinyin` has:

```
copy "iso14651_t1_common"
```

And then specifies ordering for many additional Chinese characters, while `en_US` only uses `iso14651_t1_common`.

If you set `LC_CTYPE` (via `LANG`) to zh_CN.GB18030 or zh_CN.GBK and try to process a file encoded in UTF-8, `sort` will typically fail to decode the lines into text as the bytes of UTF-8 encoded text typically don't form valid GB18030 encoded text and you'll make the problem a lot worse.

Here, if you want to get unique (as per byte-to-byte comparison) lines but also want to get a "properly" sorted output in your locale, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -u your-file | sort
```

Where the first `sort` removes duplicates and the second sorts the remaining lines as per your locale collation order.

We use `LC_ALL` instead of `LANG` or `LC_CTYPE`+`LC_COLLATE` because that's the variable that overrides it all (`LC_ALL` has precedence over `LC_individual_setting` which has precedence over `LANG`) so it still works if `LANG` or `LC_COLLATE` is otherwise also set in the environment.

In theory, you could also do:

```
LC_ALL= LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

so as to set only the "character type" and "collation" settings, leaving the other locale categories alone (covered by `LANG` or `LC_xxx`), but the remaining one used by `sort` is `LC_MESSAGES` used in error messages for instance, and if you set `LC_CTYPE=C`, only US-English messages can be displayed properly anyway as it's only got ASCII characters. For example:

```
$ LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN LC_CTYPE=C sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
??? GPLv3+:GNU ???????? 3 ?????? <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>?
????????:??????????????
?????????,????????

? Mike Haertel ? Paul Eggert ???
```

You'll find more details at:

- [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745)
- [Using uniq on unicode text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469347)
- [What is the difference between "sort -u" and "sort | uniq"?](/a/76095)

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, the primary unit is not *character* but *collating element* which can be made of more that one character like  `ch` that sorts between `h` and `i` in some Czech locales.</sup>

<sup>² Beware some `sort` implementations (not GNU `sort`) would also choke on NUL characters or excessively long lines.</sup>

Comment: Is it intentional that you've written `LC_ALL= LC_CTYPE=C LC_COLLATE=C`; that is, setting LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE to "C" but LC_ALL to ""?

Comment: @AndrewRay, yes setting `LC_ALL=` has the same effect as unsetting it. We need to unset it as otherwise whatever value it had before if any would take precedence.

Comment: So, if I am understanding this correctly, you are saying that sorting Chinese letters using ___sort___ is a matter of... (Wait for it.) "**a pinyin**"?  ;)